# How do I get people to vote on my questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Looking through my post history, it appears I have a bunch of questions posted that have 0 votes. This is leading to what I believe is a premature, even if justified, judgment of my ability to formulate questions that are a good fit for this Website.

**As a user, what can I do to get people to either downvote or upvote my questions?**

Comment: Just try writing a bad question, especially in a topic with heavy traffic.

Comment: Well, what tags are you posting with? For instance, if you post in [tag:javascript], you'll get plenty of votes (and answers, no matter how bad your question is), but if you post in, say, [tag:tizen] (to pick a niche tag randomly), you might not see any activity for a long while.

Comment: @Glorfindel or write a C++ question and tag it with both C and C++.

Comment: I don't think it should be hard to get downvotes on questions. So perhaps you should just be asking "*As a user, what can I do to get people to upvote my questions*?".

Comment: To get votes on question you may want to ask one... Consider asking new question useful for a lot of people for upvotes (see other comments for getting downvotes).

Comment: The magic formula is a simple one.  If you want to get votes from people that spend their free time on this web site then you only have to do one thing: don't bore them.

Answer (score 6):

First and foremost, don't worry about the number of votes on it - make sure that your question is **clear**, **concise**, and **on topic** for the site.

Then, the main thing you can do is attach a bounty to your question and hope that will attract a few more hits along to it.  If your question is good and concise, the people that you attract may cast a vote or two on it as well.

But above all, focus on the **quality** of your question.  No one wants terrible questions upvoted, and nobody wants their question downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Bounty is official way to ask for more attention to the question.

You can also call for [META-effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect), but... zero is really good score for most questions.

Posting on META should be used only when you really need feedback on the question. Random meta post with "why no one looks at my question {link to question}" will bring downvotes for essentially wasting viewers time. Obviously votes would not come for better reason, but it is very rare to see question that was never edited (to get into review or home page) and at the same time is flawless example of SO question.